# create instance of class within class definition

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a default instance of a class. I want to have

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        ....

    _default = Foo()

    @staticmethod
    def get_default():
        return _default
```

However `_default = Foo()` leads to `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`

Comment: Note that `__init` is not a special method; it's `__init__`.

Comment: Meanwhile, this smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Many people who want to do this, but have no idea how, are trying to write Java-style code in Python, when there's actually a much better way to solve their real problem. So, _why_ do you want a "default instance" that you get with a `staticmethod` like this? Why not, e.g., just have a global `default_foo` object? (Yes, globals are bad—but singletons _are_ globals, they just hide their globalness in a way that solves none of the problems but makes things more complicated).

Comment: For that matter, even if you _do_ want the global default instance to be owned by the class, why do you want a getter method for it? That's almost always a sign of a non-pythonic design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foo` does not exist until the class definition is finalized.  You can easily refer to it *after* the class definition, though:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
    # ....

Foo.default_instance = Foo()
```

Note also that I have removed the superfluous getter method in favor of a plain old attribute.

You can also solve the problem with a decorator:

```
def defaultinstance(Class):
    Class.default_instance = Class()
    return Class

@defaultinstance
class Foo(object):
    # ...
```

Or, gratuitously, with a metaclass:

```
def defaultmeta(name, bases, attrs):
    Class = type(name, bases, attrs)
    Class.default_instance = Class()
    return Class

# Python 2.x usage
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = defaultmeta
    # ...

# Python 3.x usage
class Foo(metaclass=defaultmeta):
    # ...
```

When might you might want to use each method?

- Use the post-definition class attribute assignment for one-offs
- Use the decorator if you want the same behavior in a lot of unrelated classes and to "hide" the implementation of it (it's not really hidden, or even that complicated, here, though)
- Use the metaclass if you want the behavior to be *inheritable* in which case it's not really gratuitous.  :-)

Comment: I think you want to delete the `_default = Foo()` line in the middle there.

Comment: Calling `Foo.get_default()` will raise a `NameError` for `_default`.

Comment: Yeah, I foolishly cut and pasted the OP's original code there.

Comment: +1 for gratuitous metaclass answer! but seriously, the first one is the way I would go.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer to a class that doesn't yet exist. Within the class definition body, the `Foo` class is *not yet created*.

Add the attribute after the class has been created:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        ....

    @staticmethod
    def get_default():
        return Foo._default


Foo._default = Foo()
```

Note that you also need to alter the `get_default()` static method; the class body doesn't form a scope, so you cannot reach `_default` as a non-local from `get_default()`.

You are now, however, repeating yourself a lot. Reduce repetition a little by making `get_default()` a classmethod instead:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        ....

    @classmethod
    def get_default(cls):
        return cls._default


Foo._default = Foo()
```

or create the default on first call:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        ....

    @classmethod
    def get_default(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_default'):
            cls._default = cls()
        return cls._default
```

Answer (score 0):

You may lazily initialize your default instance.

```
class Foo(object):

    _default = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_default():
        if not Foo._default:
            Foo._default = Foo()
        return Foo._default
```

Comment: trying to avoid the lazy initialization since its not thread safe